# TexMaker produces !Missing \endcsname

Tags: texmaker

It's been a while since I've done TeX. I am working with TeXMaker on Mac:

```
\begin 
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\author{me}
\title{my title}
\begin{document}
\part{Part One}
Text
\end{document}
```

It claims there is an error on line 2:

```
LOG FILE :
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex 2018.4.16) 4 JUL 2018 14:57
entering extended mode
restricted \write18 enabled.
%&-line parsing enabled.
**my-file-name.tex
(./my-file-name.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
! Missing \endcsname inserted.
<to be read again>
\let
l.2 \documentclass
[10pt,a4paper]{article}
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000].
\documentclass ->\let \documentclass
\@twoclasseserror \if@compatibility \el...
l.2 \documentclass
[10pt,a4paper]{article}
If you really absolutely need more capacity,
you can ask a wizard to enlarge me.
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
5 strings out of 492650
179 string characters out of 6129648
60420 words of memory out of 5000000
3988 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
3640 words of font info for 14 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
5000i,0n,4p,64b,16s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
No pages of output.
```

I got this code by using the "quick start" function in texmaker. I am utterly confused, why it's choking on this code.

One theory I have is that I missing a package or something, but that doesn't make sense with the error and texmaker has not prompted me for a package. I don't see anywhere to manage packages.

When I installed Tex (separately) I used TexLive to install packages and it appears I have the amsmath package at the very least.

[image: amsmath is there at least]

Any idea what's going wrong? I just want to test out TexMaker so I can write a paper.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Remove that `\begin` in the first line and it will work :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin in the first line of the file is causing it.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!